# Getting random results with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm new to Doctrine and had a hard time deciding how to get random rows within it without creating custom DQL functions or using a native query. 
The solution I have come up with is below, this is within a custom repository for an Entity. I'm hoping for some constructive criticism in regards to it, however it currently is working.

```
class MyRepository extends EntityRepository
{

/**
 * @param int $numberOfResults
 * @return array
 */
public function getRandomResults($numberOfResults = 1)
{
    $maxID = $this->getMax();
    $count = 0;
    $randomNumberCounter = 0;
    $randomNumbers = array();
    while ($randomNumberCounter < $numberOfResults) {
        $randomNumberCounter++;
        $randomNumbers[] = $this->getRandom(0, $maxID);
    }

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
    while ($count < $numberOfResults) {
        $qb
            ->andWhere(
                $qb->expr()->orX(
                    // the greater than is to account for holes within the primary key
                    $qb->expr()->gte("r.id", "?".$count),
                    /* the less than is in case we have a beginning database with a large disparity
                    between starting and ending ID */
                    $qb->expr()->lte("r.id", "?".$count)
                )
            );
        $count++;
    }
    $result = $qb
        ->setParameters($randomNumbers)
        ->setMaxResults($numberOfResults)
        // ensure we have no duplicates
        ->groupBy('r.id')
        ->getQuery();

    return $result->getResult();
}


/**
 * get the maximum ID that the table has
 * @return mixed
 * TODO: Create a Cron job to set this every 6 hours
 */
public function getMax()
{
    $maxID = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->select('(MAX(r.id))')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
    return $maxID;
}

/**
 * @param $min
 * @param $max
 * @return int
 */
public function getRandom($min, $max)
{
    return mt_rand($min, $max);
}
}
```

Comment: I guess you need it there http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, my fault for not realizing codereview existed!